# How put text above line

Tags: pdftex, line

I would like to be able to put the letter k on top of a line that a t and t′ as shown in Figure. With \xrightarrow you can but I don't want the arrow to be there someone knows how?.

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer, which you have thanked.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$t\mathrel{\stackon[-1pt]{{-}\mkern-4mu{-}}{\scriptstyle k}}t'$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the line a bit longer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$t\mathrel{\stackon[-1pt]{{-}\mkern-5mu{-}\mkern-5mu{-}}{\scriptstyle k}}t'$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!